# Calling a Delegate of an instance method on a Generic

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, delegates

I'm not having much luck searching for this answer, as I think that I don't know enough about the proper terms for it.

(Edit for clarity of code and how I call it)

I have a class that instantiates an extension method:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static IList<T> Bar<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
    {
        IList<T> list = ... // do something with DataTable.

        return list;
    }
}
```

I call this method like this:

```
DataTable table = SomehowGetTable();

IList<MyObject> list = table.Bar<MyObject>();
```

Again, greatly simplified.

Now, what I'd like to do, is add a delegate(?) so that after I get the list, I can call a method on each T in the list, like so:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static IList<T> Bar<T>(this DataTable table, MyDelegate postProcess)
    {
        IList<T> list = ... // do something with DataTable.

        foreach(T item in list)
        {
            t.postProcess();
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

I don't know what I need to be able to pass in postProcess.. a delegate, a Predicate, or an Action, mostly because I'm Linq-challenged still.

Or, maybe this isn't even possible?

Comment: Your first sample isn't working either, is it? No way to infer `T` from `DataTable`.

Comment: Nor is `Bar` defined as generic, and `T` is not defined anywhere else (assuming there's no actual type named `T`, of course)

Comment: I greatly reduced the code down from what I actually have, and inadvertently left off some thing, as I was in a rush to get this question posted to get something to work. The first sample does work in my world... I'll see if I can edit it to make more sense.

Comment: Henk and Adam, I just realized what you were pointing out. Editing for that point now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature would be

```
public static IList<T> Bar<T>(this DataTable table, Action<T> postProcess) {
  var list = // Get ILIst<T> from DataTable
  foreach (var i in list)
  postProcess(i);
}
```

These days .Net brings virtually all method signatures to the table that you may ever need through `Action` and `Func` delegates. While action covers all void return type methods, Func introduces non-void returns.

Note that T must be defined as type argument on your method. The compiler may be able to infer T from the action you provide into the method:

```
List<double> myDoubles = table.Bar((double x) => Debug.Writeline(x));
```

For example if you are actually processing the values coming into a different type, the signature may look like :

```
public static IList<Z> Bar<T,Z>(this DataTable table, Func<T,Z> postProcess) {
  return /* Get Listof T */ .Select(postProcess).ToList();
}
```

Used like

```
List<int> values = table.Bar((double d) => (int)d);
```

Comment: I'm accepting this one as it was technically first according to stackoverflow, and also for providing a sample to call it with.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is an Action< T > so you can do:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static IList<T> Bar(this DataTable table, Action<T> postProcess)
    {
        IList<T> list = ... // do something with DataTable.

        foreach(T item in list)
        {
            postProcess(item);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: T is the generic type of the items in your IList. Am I not understanding you correctly?

Comment: The list is the return Type. See Adam's answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to define `Bar` as generic, otherwise it won't compile.

Second, if you're trying to operate on each element within the list, you need to pass in a delegate that takes a single parameter of type `T` and returns no value. A built-in .NET delegate type is `Action<T>`, and it'll do fine.

So,

```
public static IList<T> Bar<T>(this DataTable table, Action<T> postProcess)
{
    IList<T> list = ... // do something with DataTable

    foreach(T item in list)
    {
        postProcess(item);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Action<T>`:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static IList<T> Bar(this DataTable table, Action<T> postProcess)
    {
        IList<T> list = ... // do something with DataTable.

        foreach(T item in list)
        {
            postProcess(item);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Or use an **interface** so you do not have to pass action: (I prefer this one)

```
public interface IDo
{ 
    Do();
}

public static class Foo
{
    public static IList<T> Bar(this DataTable table) where T : IDo
    {
        IList<T> list = ... // do something with DataTable.

        foreach(T item in list)
        {
            item.Do();
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do either

```
public static IList<T> Bar<T>(this DataTable table, Action<T> postProcess)
{
   ...
   postProcess(someT);
   ...
}
```

or add a generic constraint:

```
public static IList<T> Bar<T>(this DataTable table)
   where T : IHasPostProcess
{
   ...
   someT.postProcess();
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `T : IHasPostProcess`